# Using "an eight" wrong or right?

Tags: american-english, british-english, vowels

Vowels must start with 'a' so how we can say with eight '*an eight*'? Even eight is plural. For example, set of eight elements or objects?

Comment: Can you give an example of some sentence in which "an eight" is used?

Comment: It was in some story but now I forget in which . Sorry

Comment: You seem to be asking about several different things: whether to use a or an before vowel sounds, plurality of "eight …", and maybe using a/an with plurals. Can you [edit] to clarify which you mean?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It+is+eight%2C+it+is+an+eight%2C+they+are+eight&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIt%20is%20eight%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20is%20an%20eight%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthey%20are%20eight%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I think the comments under the accepted answer clarify what is being asked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eight is a number. Numbers are normally used as determiners like a/an/the/some/any. When you use a number as a determiner, it is always singular and will not take a determiner (it is itself a determiner).

> I have **some** books
>   I have **eight** books

A number can also work as a noun

- when it specifies how many elements are in a set
- to describe the rank of something like a playing card or a banknote
- for digits

> a [six](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(cricket)) - when a cricketer hits the ball over the boundary
>   a ten of spades - a playing card
>   an [eight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_(rowing)) - a boat with eight oarsmen and a coxswain

When eight is used as a noun, it can take a determiner (a/the/an/some) and it can be plural.

> My new phone number ends with a six and three eights
>   Five eights are forty
>   I thought that three sixes was pretty good, but he had four eights! [poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hand_categories)
>   The May [bumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bumps_race) start this week-end: it's very impressive seeing several eights on the river at once!

Comment: _He had four eights! No wonder I couldn’t draw an eight to complete my straight_. (Just adding an example where _an eight_ could be used.)

Comment: An 8-year old boy?